# Ccle miRna data units

Tags: rna-seq, public-databases, cancer

Does anybody know what units the mirna expression data on ccle is in? I saw the pipeline in the original paper but it doesn't mention units.

Original paper: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1186-3?proof=t

Data: https://portals.broadinstitute.org/ccle/data